# Why does Multi-thread cyrus delay forking of imapd processes after connecting to master listener

Tags: imap, cyrus

Apologies for long post, most of it is configuration details.

I have recently changed from a single threaded cyrus server in which multiple domains were overloaded on one listener as multiple virtual domains to a multiple threaded cyrus server in which multiple domains are listened for on separate ip addresses with separate configurations. The primary motivation was to have separate tls certificates for each domain. The problem is that I can connect to cyrus listener on all ip/ports for all domains, but while one of them will fork immediately and respond with a banner, the others will delay for a period of time from a few seconds to a minute or so before forking and responding with a banner. With the same setup, I change to a single threaded cyrus server to listen on all ip/ports then I get an immediate response on all, but of course I do not get the separate tls certificate or configuration. It is replicable that switching between the single threaded and multiple threaded configuration triggers the problem. I have searched the logs and the mail-lists and found nothing that seems related.

Question: why does switching to multiple threaded cyrus server trigger delayed forking of imapd processes after connecting to master listener?

On listener which responds immediately (as expected) I get this:

```
user@somehost:~> telnet imap.domain1.com 143
Trying 192.168.110.171...
Connected to imap.domain1.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ID ENABLE STARTTLS AUTH=GSS-SPNEGO AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN SASL-IR] imap.domain1.com Cyrus IMAP v2.4.18 server ready
```

On listener with delay, I get this (and process hangs for many seconds or even a minute or two):

```
user@somehost:~> telnet imap.domain2.com 143
Trying 192.168.110.172...
Connected to imap.domain2.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The domain for which the listener responds and the one for which it delays seems to change and be random as far as I can tell.

There is nothing in the log journal that looks different from when we connect and get a for and when we connect and get a delay.

```
May 19 09:44:31 MAILSERVER master[13762]: about to exec /usr/lib/cyrus/bin/imapd
May 19 09:44:31 MAILSERVER imap[13762]: executed
May 19 09:44:31 MAILSERVER imap[13762]: IOERROR: opening /var/lib/imap/user_deny.db: No such file or directory
```

and once imapd forks and banner is generated

May 19 09:46:45 MAILSERVER imap[13762]: accepted connection

```
START {
# do not delete this entry!
recover cmd="ctl_cyrusdb -r"

# this is only necessary if using idled for IMAP IDLE
idled cmd="idled"
}

# UNIX sockets start with a slash and are put into /var/lib/imap/socket
SERVICES {
# add or remove based on preferences
#imap cmd="imapd" listen="imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf " listen="192.168.171.4:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf " listen="192.168.110.171:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain2.com.conf " listen="192.168.172.4:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain2.com.conf " listen="192.168.110.172:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain3.com.conf " listen="192.168.174.4:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain3.com.conf " listen="192.168.110.174:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain4.com.conf " listen="192.168.175.4:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain4.com.conf " listen="192.168.110.175:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain5.com.conf " listen="192.168.176.4:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain5.com.conf " listen="192.168.110.176:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain6.com.conf " listen="192.168.177.4:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imap cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain6.com.conf " listen="192.168.110.177:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100

#imaps cmd="imapd -s" listen="imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.171.4:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.110.171:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain2.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.172.4:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain2.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.110.172:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain3.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.174.4:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain3.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.110.174:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain4.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.175.4:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain4.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.110.175:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain5.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.176.4:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain5.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.110.176:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain6.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.177.4:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
imaps cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain6.com.conf -s " listen="192.168.110.177:imaps" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100

#pop3 cmd="pop3d" listen="pop3"
#pop3s cmd="pop3d -s" listen="pop3s"
#sieve cmd="timsieved" listen="sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf" listen="192.168.171.4:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf" listen="192.168.110.171:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain2.com.conf" listen="192.168.172.4:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain2.com.conf" listen="192.168.110.172:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain3.com.conf" listen="192.168.174.4:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain3.com.conf" listen="192.168.110.174:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain4.com.conf" listen="192.168.175.4:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain4.com.conf" listen="192.168.110.175:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain5.com.conf" listen="192.168.176.4:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain5.com.conf" listen="192.168.110.176:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain6.com.conf" listen="192.168.177.4:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
sieve cmd="timsieved -C /etc/imapd.domain6.com.conf" listen="192.168.110.177:sieve" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100

#ptloader cmd="ptloader" listen="/var/lib/imap/ptclient/ptsock"

# at least one LMTP is required for delivery
lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="mail.domain1.com:lmtp" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="mail.domain2.com:lmtp" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="mail.domain3.com:lmtp" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="mail.domain4.com:lmtp" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="mail.domain5.com:lmtp" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="mail.domain6.com:lmtp" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
#lmtpunix cmd="lmtpd" listen="/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp"

# this is only necessary if using notifications
#notify cmd="notifyd" listen="/var/lib/imap/socket/notify" proto="udp"
}

EVENTS {
# this is required
checkpoint cmd="ctl_cyrusdb -c" period=30

# this is only necessary if using duplicate delivery suppression,
# Sieve or NNTP
duplicateprune cmd="cyr_expire -E 3" at=0400

# Expire data older then 69 days. Two full months of 31 days
# each includes two full backup cycles, plus 1 week margin
# because we run our full backups on the first sat/sun night
# of each month.
deleteprune cmd="cyr_expire -E 4 -D 69" at=0430
expungeprune cmd="cyr_expire -E 4 -X 69" at=0445

# this is only necessary if caching TLS sessions
tlsprune cmd="tls_prune" at=0400

# Uncomment the next entry, if you want to automatically remove
# old messages of EVERY user.
# This example calls ipurge every 60 minutes and ipurge will delete
# ALL messages older then 120 days.
# enter 'man 8 ipurge' for more details
#cleanup cmd="ipurge -d 120 -f" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Spam*@domain1.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Spam*@domain2.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Spam*@domain3.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Spam*@domain4.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Spam*@domain5.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Spam*@domain6.com" period=60

cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Trash*@domain1.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Trash*@domain2.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Trash*@domain3.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Trash*@domain4.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Trash*@domain5.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 30 user/%/Trash*@domain6.com" period=60

cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 60 user/%/Sent*@domain1.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 60 user/%/Sent*@domain2.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 60 user/%/Sent*@domain3.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 60 user/%/Sent*@domain4.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 60 user/%/Sent*@domain5.com" period=60
cleanup cmd="ipurge -f -d 60 user/%/Sent*@domain6.com" period=60

# Create search indexes regularly
squatter cmd="squatter -s -i" at=0530

# running sa-learn
sa-learn cmd="/usr/local/bin/cyrus-salearn.pl" period=60
sa-update cmd="/usr/bin/sa-update -v" at=0000

}
```

/etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf

```
configdirectory: /var/lib/imap
partition-default: /var/spool/imap
sievedir: /var/lib/sieve
annotation_definitions: /etc/imapd.annotations.conf
# admins: cyrus@domain1.net
allowanonymouslogin: no
autocreatequota: 10000
reject8bit: no
quotawarn: 90
timeout: 30
poptimeout: 10
dracinterval: 0
drachost: localhost
sasl_pwcheck_method: saslauthd

lmtp_overquota_perm_failure: no
#lmtp_catchall_mailbox: admin
lmtp_downcase_rcpt: yes
lmtp_fuzzy_mailbox_match: yes
expunge_mode: delayed
deletedprefix: DELETED
delete_mode: delayed

allowplaintext: yes
unixhierarchysep: yes
allowplainwithouttls: no
altnamespace: no
virtdomains: userid
servername: imap.domain1.com

#
# if you want lTLS, you have to generate certificates and keys
#
tls_cert_file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/imap.domain1.com/cert.pem
tls_key_file: /etc/letsencrypt/live/imap.domain1.com/privkey.pem
tls_ca_fie: /etc/letsencrypt/live/imap.domain1.com/chain.pem
tls_ca_path: /etc/ssl/certs
tls_versions: tls1_0 tls1_1 tls1_2

lmtp_admins: lmtpuser
```

Note: before I discovered the problem with forking could be triggered by switching between single threaded and multi-threaded cyrus server, I thought problem could be related to resource constraints. This is why I set all processes with maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100. I also set the following in /etc/systemd/system/cyrus.service

/etc/systemd/system/cyrus.service

```
[deleted...]
LimitRTPRIO=50000
LimitNOFILE=50000
LimitNPROC=50000
```

None of these resource settings made any difference and the problem goes away as soon as cyrus is single threaded - so I do not believe it is a resource constraint (at least one I understand at this point).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was provided by Edda on info-cyrus@lists.andrew.cmu.edu.

The problem is all the processes in services section have same name causing them to need to write to same lock files var/lib/imap/socket.  Renaming the processes in the service section with unique names, alphanumeric only [a-z0-9] causes the blocking to stop.

/etc/cyrus.com becomes the following:

```
    SERVICES {
    # add or remove based on preferences
    imap1 cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf " listen="192.168.171.4:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100
    imap2 cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd.domain1.com.conf " listen="192.168.110.171:imap" maxchild=-1 maxforkrate=100

etc...
```

Thanks, Edda